# Ratchet Toggle - Setting Variable through Angular Directive and Accessing from Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle, ratchet

I am new to Angular and want to set the value of scope variable from directive and access it from the template file, but it's not working.

I am using Ratchet Toggle, and want to get all toggles that the user has turned off. I was able to write to the console but was not able to read from the template file.

Here's my directive:

```
mobileApp.directive('whenToggled', [function() {
    function linkFunction(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                var has_class = element.hasClass('active');
                var id = element.attr('id');
                if(has_class==false){
                    scope.unwanted_ingredients += id;
                }
                else
                    scope.unwanted_ingredients = "none";
             },0)
        }, function(value) {
            //
        });

    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: linkFunction,
    };
}]);
```

and here's my template code:

```
Ingredients: {{unwanted_ingredients}}

<ul class="table-view">
    <li class="table-view-cell">
        Item 1
        <div id="item1" class="toggle" when-toggled ng-click="">
        <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="table-view-cell">
        Item 2
        <div id="item2" class="toggle active" when-toggled ng-click="">
        <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="table-view-cell">
        Item 3
        <div id="item3" class="toggle" when-toggled ng-click="">
        <div class="toggle-handle active"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="table-view-cell">
        Item 4
        <div id="item4" class="toggle" when-toggled ng-click="">
        <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

unwanted_ingredients is being populated on initial load as I set it on the controller as:

```
$scope.unwanted_ingredients = "abc";
```

but the value is not being changed through the directive link. I appreciate your input on this as I don't understand well how scopes works with Angular.